# TensorFlow saved model export conversion to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-lite

**TLDR**: 
I get a `ValueError:` when running

```
tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_saved_model()
```

**Aims**: I am trying to convert a TensorFlow saved model to tflite for deployment on mobile devices via Firebase. I can train the model and output a saved model but I am having trouble converting it to `.tflite` with the python ToCo interface. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if anyone can comment on whether the tflite conversion will capture the `hub.text_embedding_column()` input process that I am relying on. Will the mobile deployment execute this with raw input text or do I need to deploy that part of it separately?

**Question**: here is the code I am running:

INPUTS:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    train_df, train_df["target_var"], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True
)

predict_train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    train_df, train_df["target_var"], shuffle=False
)

predict_test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    test_df, test_df["target_var"], shuffle=False)

embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="text", 
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1"
)
```

TRAIN AND EVALUATE:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[500, 100],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
    n_classes=2,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003),
    model_dir="my-model"
)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

train_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn)
test_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)
```

SAVE MODEL:

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([embedded_text_feature_column])

serve_input_fun = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
    feature_spec,
    default_batch_size=None
)

estimator.export_savedmodel(
    export_dir_base = "my-model",
    serving_input_receiver_fn = serve_input_fun,
    as_text=False,
    checkpoint_path="my-model/model.ckpt-1000",
)
```

CONVERT MODEL:

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_saved_model("my-model/1529320265/") 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

**Error**

When running the last line I get the following error:

> ValueError: Tensors input_example_tensor:0 not known type tf.string

And the full trace is:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   1 converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_saved_model("my-model/1529320265/")
>   ----> 2 tflite_model = converter.convert()
>
> /media/rmn/data/projects/anaconda3/envs/monily_tf19/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self)
>   307    reorder_across_fake_quant=self.reorder_across_fake_quant,
>   308    change_concat_input_ranges=self.change_concat_input_ranges,
>   --> 309         allow_custom_ops=self.allow_custom_ops)
>   310    return result
>   311
>   /media/rmn/data/projects/anaconda3/envs/monily_tf19/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, inference_type, inference_input_type, input_format, output_format, quantized_input_stats, default_ranges_stats, drop_control_dependency, reorder_across_fake_quant, allow_custom_ops, change_concat_input_ranges)
>   204     else:
>   205       raise ValueError("Tensors %s not known type %r" % (input_tensor.name,
>   --> 206        input_tensor.dtype))
>   207
>   208     input_array = model.input_arrays.add()
>
> ValueError: Tensors input_example_tensor:0 not known type tf.string

**Details**

`train_df` and `test_df` are pandas dataframes consisting of a single input text column and a binary target variable. I am using Python 3.6.5 and TensorFlow r1.9.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed on TensorFlow's `master` branch (in commit [d3931c8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d3931c804ce9619ac0a0c84f42b43ce70ade93a7#diff-86ba9617dbaf4026f6266f9a900b429f)). Reference the following documentation on TensorFlow's website to build a pip installation from GitHub: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources.